# Download a file from a Claims auth based SharePoint 2010 site programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have a console application to download a file from a SharePoint site. The sharepoint site uses claims based authentication.

This code throws a 403 Forbidden exception. The specified Network credential has full access to the site, and is able to download the same file from a browser.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,Password,domain);
byte[] fileData = webClient.DownloadData(urlOfAFile); 
FileStream file = File.Create(localPath);
file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is the site set to require ssl (check directoy security in IIS)

Comment: Yes... The site is configured to use HTTPS

Comment: Any luck with this problem?  I am running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a bit late, but adding the right request header before making the request solves the problem:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. After adding your code snipped, I am getting a 401 Exception. Earlier, I was getting a 403 exception. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you trying to log in with Windows authentication or Forms authentication?

Comment: Hi @ashwnacharya Have you solved this problem? I also have the same problem, if you know how to solve it, can you post your answer here? Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me! I tried the [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316111/system-net-webclient-request-gets-403-forbidden-but-browsers-do-not-with-apache) provided in the same forum which did not work for me.

Comment: I had to add the user agent header also and then it worked. _SPWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC)";

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this issue, and below is my research:

```
{
  ClientContext m_clientContext = new ClientContext(strSiteUrl);
    m_clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_MixedAuthRequest);
    m_clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    m_clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uname, pwd);
    Web m_currentWeb = m_clientContext.Web;
    m_clientContext.Load(m_currentWeb);
    m_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}

  private void ctx_MixedAuthRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Add the header that tells SharePoint to use Windows authentication.
            e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Add(
            "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error setting authentication header: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

here is the article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh124553(v=office.14).aspx