# Not getting the page source of a web page through WebClient in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, webclient

c# webclient returns 403 and 301 on working page. How to get rid of this.This is my code.

```
TimedWebClient wclient = new TimedWebClient();
//This is a object extend WebClient

byte[]  pagesource = wclient.DownloadData(requestUrl);
UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
string responseData = objUTF8.GetString(pagesource);
```

This works with some urls, but doesn't with others
For example: The url is :   http://toyotaofmanhattan.com/

```
"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}System.Exception  {System.Net.WebException}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.Thank you.

Comment: It could be detecting the fact that you have no user-agent and thus suspects a robot or similar. Try setting a user-agent; see this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316128/1073107

Comment: just use try catch so if the url wont load display a text saying for example sorry can't load the specific url

Comment: _"Please provide me a a code"_, _"Please give me a working code"_ - do you actually want to understand the problem, or do you just want it to work?

Comment: @liquidsnake786 no it is a httpurl.

Comment: @CodeCaster sure i want to understand it. But when u have the code u can do both. i don't just copy and be happy. I'll getin to that and understand what wasn't there before and what is now there and what was the error.

Answer (score -1):

try using Fiddler. Check what browser send to see the page, and what you do not send to get error. It probably is different for every page.

Comment: This answer should be as a comment....

Comment: @Rony why exactly? It provides tools and methodologies for question owner to solve his/her problem. This is what I use for scrapping web pages.

Comment: i know but this sentance you can say in comment section...This not his/her answer.... am i correct????

Comment: His/her problem is that some pages do give error. Underlying problem is he/she does not send correct metadata/header/request parameters. Question owner must solve underlying problem. My answer is to show how underlying problem can be solved. There is no silver bullet solution to this problem since requirements for each site is different.